# How to define as a view for an AlertDialog a view described in a XML file

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Here is my problem. I would like to have an AlertDialog that have a title and a positive button. I want to describe the content of the AlertDialog in a XML file (except for the title/button).
I have created a file called `dlg_addpwd.xml` in my layout resources.
Here is the code I'm using:

```
  AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  
  alert.setTitle("Password access");
  alert.setView(findViewById(R.layout.dlg_addpwd));
  alert.setPositiveButton("Add", listenAddPwdDlg);
  alert.show();
```

I guess the line

```
  alert.setView(findViewById(R.layout.dlg_addpwd));
```

is wrong, isn't it ?
So the main idea of my question is: how to define as a view for an AlertDialog a view described in a XML file?

Thanks

Vincent

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
        getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.paypaldialog, 
        (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourDialog));
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourClass.this)
        .setView(layout);
    alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```

that is how I do it.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to [Customizing the Alert dialog in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782508/customizing-the-alert-dialog-in-android/4782587#4782587) to create a custom Alert Dialog.

The main problem with your code is that you don't want to use `AlertDialog.Builder`. Instead you want to create a new `Dialog`, and use `setContentView()` to render your XML.