# Alert dialog box in android

Tags: android

i m using a alert dialog box in my application,when alert dialog box appears my whole activity goes to background and a black appears.i want that when dialog box appears then my activity looks as it is as it looks before,i don't wan any background scenario?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use transparent flag for your dialog. But probably you gonna need to create your custom dialog for it:

```
Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(mContext, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);
```

Custom dialog: 
[android dialog transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059068/android-dialog-transparent)

AlertBox: [Set Transparent Window in AlertDialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800334/set-transperent-window-in-alertdialog-box)

Comment: R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen is not working with my custom dialog box....

Comment: public CustomizeDialog(Context context) {
  super(context);
  mContext = context;
  /** 'Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE' - Used to hide the mTitle */
  requestWindowFeature(android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
//  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  /** Design the dialog in main.xml file */
  setContentView(R.layout.customdialog);
  v = getWindow().getDecorView();
  v.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);

Comment: when my dialog is appear then background colour of my activity is being low,looks like little bit black,what i want is when dialog is in foreground then there is no change in background activity

Comment: public class CustomizeDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {
@Override
public void onWindowAttributesChanged(LayoutParams params) {
super.onWindowAttributesChanged(params);}                           ContextmContext;                                                             public CustomizeDialog(Context context) {
  super(context);
  mContext =context;requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  setContentView(R.layout.customdialog);
  v = getWindow().getDecorView();
 v.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);}

Comment: try: super(context, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);

Comment: i just test it and it works for me. Maybe there is something wrong with your xml layout?

Comment: there is xml in Custom Dialog example link which I included to my answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 public class CustomDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {      
  Button button_home,button_cancel,button_resume;     
    public GamePauseMenu(Context context) {          
      super(context,R.style.Theme_Transparent);      
      }     


    public void show(int bg) {              
             super.show();         
           setContentView(R.layout.custdialog);       
            button_resume = (Button)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);                  button_resume.setOnClickListener(this);    
     }     public void onClick(View v) {         cancel();      }   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        MainActivity.this);

// Setting Dialog Title
                alertDialog2.setTitle("Confirm Delete...");

// Setting Dialog Message
                alertDialog2.setMessage("Are you sure you want delete this file?");

// Setting Icon to Dialog
               // alertDialog2.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);

// Setting Positive "Yes" Btn
                alertDialog2.setPositiveButton("YES",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // Write your code here to execute after dialog
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                            }
                        });

// Setting Negative "NO" Btn
                alertDialog2.setNegativeButton("NO",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // Write your code here to execute after dialog
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "You clicked on NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

// Showing Alert Dialog
                alertDialog2.show();
            }
        });
```